# Данные не попадают в request.POST при отправке их на сервер с помощью curl

Tags: django, post, curl

**Тело post запроса не преобразуется в QueryDict**

Почему-то post запрос от curl сервер принимает без данных. Данные в body оказывается. Почему так происходит? QueryDict пустой. Скрины:
То что пришло на сервер
[image: То что пришло на сервер]
то что отправлял
[image: то что отправлял]

Comment: попробуйте передавать данные -d title=Chease -d description=Very\ well и тд.